# jquery change event works on form element - undocumented feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to handle `.change` event on all form elements, some sources recommend this:

```
$('#form_id :input').change(...)
```

But I realized the following works too:

```
$('#form_id').change(...)
```

But does it really? I tried to find this feature on [jQuery API - change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) but if I look correctly, seems undocumented?

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.

Comment: The change event, like many other events, _bubbles._

Comment: [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) event bubbles

Comment: can you provide link to those sources that recommend you change it?

Comment: @Raphaël, jQuery works around that: `As of jQuery 1.4, the change event bubbles in Internet Explorer, behaving consistently with the event in other modern browsers.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is event bubbling and capturing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing).

Comment: @Tomas - the sentence Frédéric Hamidi quoted is the documentation you are looking for. It's on the page you linked to, just before the examples.